# automatic new release in GIthub action

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have no knowledge in the yaml language, I am a designer and not a programmer, but I followed a step by step to create an atomization that would create an automatic release, but it is returning an **Error:** `Input required and not supplied: tag_name`

YAML code:

```YAML
name: Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  FILE_NAME: "Dark-Everywhere"
  FILE_EXTENSION: ".zip"
  BRANCHES: "1.19.3,1.19,1.18"
  PACKAGE_NAME: "assets,pack.mcmeta,pack.png"
  TAG_NAME: "1.0.0"
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Create a release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        tag_name: "v${{ env.TAG_NAME }}"
        release_name: "Dark Everywhere ${{ env.TAG_NAME }}"
        draft: true
        prerelease: false
    - name: Generate a zip archive for each branch
      run: |
        for branch in $(echo $BRANCHES | tr "," "\\n"); do
          zip -r "$FILE_NAME-$branch$FILE_EXTENSION" $PACKAGE_NAME
        done
    - name: Upload files
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: "$FILE_NAME-$branch$FILE_EXTENSION"
        path: "$FILE_NAME-$branch$FILE_EXTENSION"
    - name: Update release
      uses: actions/update-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        release_id: ${{ env.RELEASE_ID }}
        body: "Build description here"
```

I already tried to add `TAG_NAME: "1.0.0"` inside env in the code but the error persists

Comment: Could You please expand on Your expectations? Currently, action is triggered on every `push` to `master` branch, zipping and uploading multiple branches. You sure it's what You expect to happen?  Also, reducing the YAML sample would help a lot. Also, why putting `GITHUB_TOKEN` to `env` and directly taken from `secret`?

Comment: actually the GITHUB_TOKEN part was redundant, I already made the adjustment made by the tip,

however I'm not a programmer, I'm a graphic designer so my understanding of code is almost nil, this code was followed step by step to create it,

Comment: because I created a Texture Pack for Minecraft this texture covers 3 minecraft versions from 1.19.3 to 1.19 and 1.18, I have a branch for each version and an alpha brench where I release the updates when I modify and add everything I want in the alpha I merge it with each of the branches above and then manually I create a zip file for each version, and launch the realese, this code would make my

Comment: life easier, because that part of creating a zip for each version and publishing it in a single release would be left to git action then it would be published as a draft, then I would just go there and modify the description and actually publish it, making the job much simpler